# Web service as client of another certificate-secured service - first call returns 403, second call succeeds

Tags: iis, azure, certificate

I've got a web service in Azure, and I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue that has only cropped up while trying to migrate the systems to IIS 7.5.

My web service, when called, makes a call to another service. This call is secured via certificate. On the first instance of this communication, my connection is denied with a 403 error. On the second, and all subsequent calls, it works exactly as intended. The code path for both calls is the same, and the service object/client certificates/etc are re-initialized each time.

I cannot reproduce this behavior locally, and it only occurs on the first call (and every first call) after initialization of the web role.

I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the certificate is a red herring and you are in fact running into the first request problem. The pipe wont start listening until a request has been made but it needs a request to start listening so you can see the problem.

Have a look at employing the Auto Start feature and how to configure it to see if that helps:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285.aspx